# How do you give friends admin rights without a password to the server?

Tags: pc, garrys-mod

I was playing gmod with a friend and he couldn't use some admin items and I wanted to give him admin, but the tutorials we found said something about a password. We don't use a password when play; we just connect via ipv4 and the `connect` command. How do I give him admin rights?

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found that you should be able to add admins by altering the `users.txt` file.
You can find this file in:
`STEAMFOLDER > GarrysMod > garrysmod > settings > users.txt`
In this file an entry looks like this:

```
"admin"
{
    //"garry"           "STEAM_0:1:7099"
}
```

What you should do is enter a line with the info of your friend so it ends up like this:

```
"admin"
{
    "Friends_Username"          "STEAM_0:0:0000"
}
```

You can find a steam id trough [various websites](http://steamidfinder.com/) or steam itself.

*[source that helped me get the idea](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1990111)*

Comment: It is sandbox mode and there are there cool weapons only admins can use, and I do not know how to give him admin rights. The only person who can use these cool weapons is the host.

Comment: Could you link the specific weapon so I could have a look myself?

Comment: i couldn't find the exact weapons so i found some random admins weapons http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=545802049&searchtext=Admin+weapons

Comment: I've updated the answer, if you could try this and let me know if it worked.